# Homestead/Vagrant ssh into the VM from another computer

Tags: ssh, vagrant, homestead

I've got a question regarding Homestead/Vagrant

is it possible to ssh into the Vagrant VM from another computer?

Here's my scenario:

Homestead running into a windows PC with IP 192.168.0.201

Another windows machine with ip 192.168.0.200

From the second windows machine which is my PC I want to ssh into the VM hosted on the other windows machine

if I try 
`ssh vagrant@192.168.0.201 -p 2222`
it doesn't work.

Is it possible to achieve what I want to do? if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should in principle work, but you need to make sure port 2222 is open to outside world on your host machine.
Another option would be switching to using [public_network on vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) machine, but that will cancel all the homestead forwarded ports.